# Netcode Behaviour index was out of bounds. Did you mess up the order of your NetworkBehaviours? Unity Netcode for GameObjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

So I've been following some tutorials online and have been trying to create a multiplayer 3D game, and so far, all I want to do is for two clients to be able to connect to a server, spawn their players (spheres), and move their spheres around and into each other, causing collisions.

I have created a player movement script to handle input - just simple WASD and space-jump movement.

To handle the networking, I followed Tarodev's Netcode video to set everything up.

Here is where the problem begins. Using ParrelSync, I run the game on one editor and a clone on another. I then use a GameObject with the NetworkManager script to start a host on one editor, and a client on the other. Upon connection, the client and host both spawn players, but then the problem begins. As the client's player starts falling down, the host's editor starts experiencing errors and warnings. As mentioned in the title, here they are:

[Netcode] Behaviour index was out of bounds. Did you mess up the order of your NetworkBehaviours?

[Netcode] Network variable delta message received for a non-existent behaviour. NetworkObjectId: 2, NetworkBehaviourIndex: 2

I did a bit of digging and found that the error was being thrown by a function in the NetworkObject script, but I couldn't really understand why or how to fix it, hence this post.

Errors are only thrown on the client when the host moves its player, and errors are only thrown on the host when the client moves its player. The transforms of the players are not being transmitted between host and client at all, despite the player prefab having a Client Network Transform script, and a NetworkObject script.

Here is the link to the code if you want to reproduce the error or understand it better: https://github.com/XR101/Sumo101

Any help would be appreciated as this error is driving me insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like this could be an error in the order of components on your game objects.

If there's only one component on each object, then make sure you're [instantiating them correctly on the server](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkBehaviour.html) via [`NetworkServer.Spawn`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0/api/UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkServer.html#UnityEngine_Networking_NetworkServer_Spawn_GameObject_)

If you're sure you've done those things, then it's probably a component mismatch due to `PlayerMovement` and `PlayerMovement2` being used. I have zero experience with Unity's networking stuff but it seems from the docs that they're intended to communicate with a `NetworkBehaviour` of the same type.

Comment: I did not do any manual instantiation of GameObjects myself. All I did was add a NetworkManager script to a GameObject, which I use to start a host and a client. I was under the impression that this script does the instantiation for me. Also, What do you mean by the order of components on my game objects? Each player prefab has many components on it, ranging from a Rigidbody to a NetworkObject script. Thank you very much for your reply and I hope you enlighten me more.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed the problem, but I don't really know how - I just readded all the components to my Player Prefab and didn't touch their order in the inspector, since you said that the error could be in the order of components on the GameObjects. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey I'm glad something worked. using two different scripts? not sure i was really any help but glad you fixed the problem!

Comment: Seems like your perceptive observation about the order of components on the gameobjects had something to do with it - I wasn't previously aware but it seems the hierarchy of components in the inspector actually impacts the situation in my code. Thanks again!

Comment: well hey glad i actually was able to help  no problem!